# How can I create a sub-JSON with a few nodes selected with JSONPath?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonpath

I have currently the problem that I am not able to create a "sub-json" from a given one when I select the wanted nodes with JSONPath.

Let's say, I have the following JSON (extracted from JSONPath GitHub):

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

With the following JSONPath expression, I can extract the bicycle attributes:

```
$.store.bicycle
```

output:

```
[
   {
      "color":"red",
      "price":19.95
   }
]
```

What I really want is to create a new JSON including only the nodes that I declare with JSONPath, like:

```
{
    "store": {
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot access the parent node names with JSOnPath, I get only the values. I also do not want to parse the JSONPath expression to create the JSON (i.e. splitting the expression by "."). 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: JSONPath won't help you with that. Traverse the tree and remove the nodes you don't need.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The problem seems to be tricky... I tried to remove the nodes by traversing the tree, collecting the paths of all nodes, compare the paths with my "wanted paths" and if they do not match, I removed the node with the path. The problem gets more complex with nested nodes; I try to find a solution and will post it.

Comment: @confector did you ever find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find an "easy" way. The solution was: I list all JSON pathes and sort them. Then I iterate over the JSON pathes and check whether the current JSON path from the list starts with my "demanding" JSON path. If this is the case, then I create a new JSON object with the name of the current JSON path's object. This continues until the current JSON path equals the demanding JSON path. Long talk short sense: I re-construct the JSON manually with only the JSON objects which are nested in my JSON path.